# Accessing Instance Variable Hidden By Static Variable Without Base Keyword

Tags: c#, inheritance, hidden-field

How come I can't access the hidden instance variable a in the line (int gimmeValue = shinyNewBObject.a;) ? I understand that I can use the base keyword to access the instance a. However, I thought that the compiler would use the object reference in shinyNewBObject to rule out static variables. If the static version of a is ruled out, the instance version of a would become unhidden and therefore accessible.

What's going on here? Did the compiler create a list of all a identities in the assembly and ruled out the instance variable because it's hidden before it ruled out the other a because it's static?

```
class A
{
    public int a;
}

class B : A
{
    new public static int a;

    public void m()
    {
        B shinyNewBObject = new B();
        int gimmeValue = shinyNewBObject.a; //Error
        gimmeValue = base.a;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instance variable cannot be static

Comment: @AkashKava, It was poorly formatted before, but the instance field in question is that in `A`.

Comment: sorry about the poor formatting, I think the site did that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer:

I needed to look at the member look-up section of the specification (7.4).

"the effect of the look-up rules is simply that derived members hide base members with the same name or signature. Such single-inheritance look-ups are never ambiguous."

I think what happens when aobj.a is considered by the compiler is aobj is ignored for the time being and just a is considered.

The compiler goes to the A class definition which has all of the static and instance members implicitly or explicitly and sees the two a members. Both are accessible based on (3.5) so they go in the set of possibilities. Then the hidden variable is removed leaving the static one.

Finally 'aobj' is considered and an error occurs because an instance reference can't access the static variable.

There might be some problems with my story. If so, please correct me because I made some guesses.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not entirely sure what part of the C# spec dictates why it won't let you access the base type variable when it's obscured by a static field in the subclass, but to workaround it, you can just cast to `A`:

```
int gimmeValue = ((A)shinyNewBObject).a;
```

Comment: Apparently I can't post my own answer because I don't have enough points or whatever

Comment: I think I found the answer:

I needed to look at the member look-up section of the specification (7.4).

"the effect of the lookup rules is simply that derived members hide base members with the same name or signature. Such single-inheritance lookups are never ambiguous."

I think what happens when aobj.a is considered by the compiler is aobj is ignored for the time being and just a is considered.

Comment: The compiler goes to the A class definition which has all of the static and instance members implicitly or explicitly and sees the two a members. Both are accessible based on (3.5) so they go in the set of possibilities. Then the hidden variable is removed leaving the static one.

Finally 'aobj' is considered and an error occurs because an instance reference can't access the static variable.

There might be some problems with my story. If so, please correct me because I made some guesses.

Comment: If people like my answer, give Kirk Woll some love with upvotes

Comment: @greenonion, you can answer your own question, even if you're a new user.  You don't see anything at the bottom of the page to enter in a new one? (because it's very much in the spirit of this site to come back with your own answer after doing more research after asking)

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours to answer because I don't have 10 reputation points. I can come back and add the answer later. If I post my answer now and I'm right, I could save some people the trouble of helping me in the next 8 hours